# Installing libpng12 64-bit on Debian 12 (bookworm) 64-bit gives a multiarch-support pre-dependency error when installing Stata 16

Tags: debian, multiarch

I'm trying to install [Stata 16](https://www.stata.com/) on Debian 12 "bookworm". Stata requires `libpng12`, and unfortunately, the `libpng` in the repositories (version 16) doesn't fulfill the dependency. I've downloaded the libpng12 deb package, but when I try to install it, I get this error message about multiarch support

```
dpkg: regarding libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb containing libpng12-0:amd64, pre-dependency problem:
 libpng12-0 pre-depends on multiarch-support
  multiarch-support is not installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing libpng12-0:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
```

Both my OS and the package are 64-bit, so I'm not sure why multiarch-support is needed here. I ran `dpkg --print-architecture` and it says amd64. I thought the current version of dpkg [already had multiarch support](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO).

How do I get this package installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiarch-support` was a transitional package used during the switch to multiarch library paths.

I think the best solution for you (other than getting Stata to provide a package built using a newer version of `libpng`) is to install [a slightly newer version of `libpng12-0`](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/libpng/1.2.54-6/#libpng12-0_1.2.54-6) which doesn’t have the dependency on `multiarch-support`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the perfect solution. I wish Stata would provide newer packages! Unfortunately I only have Stata version 16. Maybe 17 and 18 are more up to date for Linux (but they're expensive).